# How to route in angular without displaying both components

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to use Angulars router to route from my landing component to my "Events" component via a button click on the landing page. Upon this button click, I want to display *only* the Events component, however when I click the button (or append "/events" to the end of the URL), the Events component displays below the landing component, displaying both components.

app.component.html:

```
<app-landing></app-landing>
```

landing.component.html:

```
<div class="landing-container">
  <div class="landing-search">
    <p> selected city: {{ selectedCity }}</p>
    <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" (click)="getCombinedResponses()"><a routerLink="/events">Search</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';
import { VenueCardsComponent } from './venues/venues.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'events', component: VenueCardsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your router-outlet needs to be in app.component.html in your case and you need to have a route for your landing page as well.

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

landing.component.html:

```
<div class="landing-container">
  <div class="landing-search">
    <p> selected city: {{ selectedCity }}</p>
    <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" (click)="getCombinedResponses()"><a routerLink="/events">Search</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';
import { VenueCardsComponent } from './venues/venues.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'events', component: VenueCardsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```